# Permission denied while starting node

Tags: substrate-node-template, docker

I am trying to build a node using the node template and this Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as builder 

ARG RUSTC_VERSION=nightly-2022-05-16
ARG PROFILE=production
# Workaround for https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10583
ENV CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true
# Incremental compilation here isn't helpful
ENV CARGO_INCREMENTAL=0

WORKDIR /code

RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    llvm \
    clang \
    make && \
    curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y --default-toolchain $RUSTC_VERSION

RUN /root/.cargo/bin/rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown

COPY Cargo.lock /code/Cargo.lock
COPY Cargo.toml /code/Cargo.toml
# COPY rust-toolchain.toml /code/rust-toolchain.toml

COPY node /code/node
COPY runtime /code/runtime
COPY pallets /code/pallets


ARG SUBSTRATE_CLI_GIT_COMMIT_HASH

RUN \
    /root/.cargo/bin/cargo build --profile $PROFILE --bin node-template && \
    mv target/$PROFILE/node-template node-template && \
    rm -rf target

FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates curl && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Use for running the node in Kubernetes
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{ "id": 1, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "system_health", "params": [] }' \
    -f "http://localhost:9933"

COPY --from=builder /code/node-template /node-template

RUN mkdir /var/substrate && chown nobody:nogroup /var/substrate

VOLUME /var/substrate

USER nobody:nogroup

ENTRYPOINT ["/node-template"]
```

However , when I try to run the image, I get the following error.

```
Error: Service(Keystore(Io(Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" })))
2022-05-26 22:20:54 Substrate Node    
2022-05-26 22:20:54 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-unknown    
2022-05-26 22:20:54 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2022    
2022-05-26 22:20:54  Chain specification: Local Testnet    
2022-05-26 22:20:54   Node name: willing-leather-5592    
2022-05-26 22:20:54  Role: FULL    
2022-05-26 22:20:54  Database: RocksDb at /nonexistent/.local/share/node-template/chains/local_testnet/db/full    
2022-05-26 22:20:54 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)
```

I will appreciate guidance on what I am doing wrong

Comment: This is likely an issue with permissions and root user vs normal user. Check that your dirs anf files are correctly setup with permissions for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the answer provided in [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/how-to-run-parachain-node-in-docker) but here are some details.

While the Polkadot Docker images **used to** run as `root`, this is no longer the case. You are shooting in your foot with `USER nobody:nogroup`  but while this is annoying you now, this is indeed the right option.

As a result, the user running your `node` does not have the right to write almost everywhere.

There a few options, some bad, some ok for testing and the good one:

### Not recommended

The quickest and **not** recommended (so I won't provide too many details about that..): run your container as `root`. No need to mention this would be a **very** bad idea for anything else than a quick test.

### Good for quick tests

A good solution for a quick test: use the `-d` flag and tell your node to put the data under `/tmp` inside your container, this folder is writable for the `polkadot` user.

### The best solution

The proper solution is to mount a volume for your data. You do this with:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /tmp:/polkadot <your_image>
```

You may pick any folder instead of `/tmp` in the example above but you must use `/polkadot` as shown above (or also provide the `-d` flag and point to the folder you want the node to use).