# How to run parachain node in Docker?

Tags: cumulus, docker

I'm trying to run a Statemint node using the [parity/polkadot-parachain](https://hub.docker.com/r/parity/polkadot-parachain/tags) docker image. However, I get this error:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash parity/polkadot-parachain

polkadot-parachain --chain statemint

2022-10-26 10:14:17 Failed to run the sequential write disk benchmark: failed to create a test file: No such file or directory (os error 2)
2022-10-26 10:14:17 Failed to run the random write disk benchmark: failed to create a test file: No such file or directory (os error 2)
Error: Service(Keystore(Io(Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" })))
```

What is a docker run command to make a parachain node work?

Comment: `--no-hardware-benchmarks` does not seem to fix it but leads to a different error 

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

You need to mount the data folder, try adding the following to your command:

```
-v /tmp:/polkadot
```

The following should solve your issue:

```
docker run -v /tmp:/polkadot --rm -it parity/polkadot-parachain --chain statemint
```

### Explanation

The issue comes from the fact that the container does not run as `root` by default and does not grant access to the local filesystem.
You can see where this is done [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/docker/injected.Dockerfile#L43).

The issue is actually not related to the parachain node and the following would fail as well:

```
touch test
```

I almost do not want to mention that running as `root` would be a **bad solution**.

The proper solution is to mount a folder as shown in the solution.

### Which folder

It does not really matter what local folder you use (I used `/tmp` in my example) as long as it exists and has sufficient space left.